# Problema con libreria AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas,

Trato de añadir la librería *compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'* a mi programa:

```
   buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

Y me da un error en el que me indica que debo instalar Android Support Repository

> Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:design:22.2.0] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

El problema está en que ya lo tengo instalado y no entiendo porque no me lo detecta.

Un saludo, gracias.

Edit:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit2:

Tras estar trasteando un poco creo que ya he encontrado la solución, y es que mi proyecto tiene 2 archivos *build.gradle* : *build.gradle(MyApplication)* y *build.gradle(app)*. He añadido la librería a esta última y no da ningún error.
Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Ahi mismo te dice que no cuentas con el repositorio, si deseas instalarlo, debes ir a tu SDKMANAGER e instalar el repositorio

Comment: intenta compilar con esto `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'`

Comment: @MiguelOsorio me publica el mismo error, pero entro en SDKManager y tengo el Android Support Repository instalado.

Comment: pero tambien tienes instalado el SDK platform a la version 22?

Comment: '
  22 1 Installed
  22 2 Installed
  22 1 Installed
  22 1 Not installed
  22 3 Not installed
  22 7 Not installed
  22 7 Not installed
  22 2 Installed
  22 5 Installed
  22 5 Installed
  22 11 Installed
  22 11 Installed
  22 11 Installed  '

Las unicas no instaladas son las que utilizan TV y Wear

Comment: Puede que me haya equivocado al añadirlo? Lo estoy añadiendo a _build.gradle(MyApplication)_

Comment: a ver tienes instalado el Android Support Repository?

Comment: es el que se encuentra ubicado en tools, esa herramienta es para que puedas añadir bibliotecas

Comment: Sí, eso es lo raro, que lo tengo instalado. Es por ello que no lo entiendo.

Comment: @J.Soto agregué una respuesta, realiza los cambios que te sugiero y comenta los resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Android Studio puedes tener varios `build.gradle`. Uno que es a nivel general de prouyecto, y uno para cada uno de los módulos que tengas dentro del proyecto. 
Típicamente solo tienes un módulo dentro del proyecto, la aplicación en si misma, y es dentro del `build.gradle` de ese módulo donde has de poner las dependencias.

En el texto que has pegado hay un mensaje:

`> // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files`

Básicamente porque el `build.gradle` que estas usando es el del proyecto, no el de tu app.

Busca otro `build.gradle` que debe estar **dentro** de tu aplicación, y pon las dependencias allí.

Comment: A lo que te refieres puede ser a la última edición de mi pregunta?

Comment: Uh parece que si, no leí el *Edit2*, perdona. Si a eso exactamente me refería.

Comment: No te preocupes, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

El problema es simplemente de configuración, si vas a usar la librería :

```
 com.android.support:design
```

Debes usar

```
com.android.support:appcompat
```

con la misma versión preferentemente (Android Studio nos obliga a tener actualizado o al menos versiones similares).

Por lo tanto en tus dependencias agrega en el `build.gradle` de tu aplicación la librería de soporte y elimina `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

}
```

Definir el classpath de la versión gradle se realiza en el `build.gradle` que esta en la raíz de tu proyecto no en el de la aplicación:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

## Actualización:

Otro problema que genera lo que se pregunta es que agregue la siguiente definición:

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1'
```

dentro del build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1' //***Provoca error.

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Esta versión posiblemente usaba "compile" en lugar de "implementation", así que al actualizar se resuelve el problema:

```
buildscript {

        ...
        ...
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
```

Comment: El problema radicaba en lo comentado por @tomacco. En el fondo es el mismo problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar Android Support Repository.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues de eso compila `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'`

Comment: En la pregunta el OP indica que el ya tiene instalado ese paquete.

Comment: Puede que me haya equivocado al añadirlo? Lo estoy añadiendo a _build.gradle(MyApplication)_ , es correcto?

Comment: si debes añadirlo en tu aplicacion

Comment: @Error404 claro pero si te das cuenta edito la pregunta despues de mi respuesta

Comment: ya está instalado, dice en la pregunta